# Updating ecoinvent with PREMISE

Tags: scenarios, brightway

I wanted to update ecoinvent(3.8) using premise for year 2030 and 2050, but I get the following error:

Could not find equivalent for ENTSO-E. when updating all
and

And Could not find equivalent for IAI Area, EU27 & EFTA - when updating only electricity!

How do I resolve this issue?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what version of premise are you using?